# MPI: Is there a way to receive variables only when it has changed?

Tags: parallel-processing, mpi

I'm working on a project where I need to implement some sort of termination detection via a variable which changes only in the root process of an MPI program.

I am struggling to understand the concepts of blocking and non-blocking instructions.

In short, only the root process can determine if the task has been completed or not. This is done by implementing a simple Boolean integer variable called "running". This has to be broadcasted to all processes in order for them to know when to exit their while-loops.

All processes run in their own while-loop. At the start, the root process sets the "running" variable to true if necessary.
The root process can then determine if the "running" variable should be set to zero and should broadcast it to all other processes.

Currently, I am using a broadcast to share this variable. Thus, whenever the loop reaches its end (or "running" gets set to zero) it broadcasts the value to all processes. Thus, each process has a broadcast inside of their function to receive the value.
I am either misunderstanding the concept of blocking or my program is not efficient.
Broadcast is blocking, thus, if the root keeps on broadcasting the variable that essentially stays the same (TRUE) for the majority of the running time, each process will essentially have to wait for the root to complete its work and then block before that process can continue with its future work.

The problem exists that since this variable only changes once in the root process, there are many unnecessary blocks happening while running. I only want the variable to be broadcasted once it has been changed to zero so that I can tell the other processes to terminate a part of their code and not have to wait for the root to broadcast every time.

```
if(myRank != 0) {
    while(running) {
        doThisFunction(myRank);
        MPI_Broadcast(... running ...); //Wait for root to broadcast?
    }
    /* Start doing something else */
} else {
    while(running || ... ) {
        /* Do stuff */
        if (...) {
            running = 0; //Somewhere in an if statement
            MPI_Broadcast(... running ...); //Now terminate the while
        }
        MPI_Broadcast(... running ...); //Unnecessary broadcast?
    }
}
```

I was thinking that I could use MPI_IProbe to check if there's a message to be received and then removing the MPI_Broadcast in the root's while-loop. If there is, then the process will initiate an MPI_Broadcast. If not, then it will continue as normal.

TL;DR:
My program terminates some code in processes if "running" equals zero. Currently, it broadcasts this in every while iteration and I think this causes the program to have an unnecessary block. I only want to send/ receive the variable when it is changed in the root.

Thanks for the help!

edit: "running" is a global variable.

Comment: Similar questions were asked before. `MPI_Ibcast()`+`MPI_Test()` is an option. `MPI_Put()` is an other one.